# How to create link to portlet and open specific tab

Tags: tabs, liferay, yui, liferay-aui

i have searched for any working example. But no success yet.
I would like to create an portlet render URL parameter, where i can add the tab, which should be shown. I suppose it has to be done with with YUI somehow.Unfortunately im still not so familier with that YUI.

Thanx for any help.

```
<div id="myTab">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a href="#tab-1">X1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2">X2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-3">X3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-4">X4</a></li>
        </ul>
```

and

```
<aui:script>

YUI().use(
          'aui-tabview',
          function(Y) {
            new Y.TabView(
              {
                srcNode: '#myTab'
              }
            ).render();
          }
        );

</aui:script>
```

Comment: Would you elaborate more what you want to achieve? and where do you stuck?

Comment: Yep, i would like to create a link to the tab-1 for example with the portlet render url schema. The scripts above are the fragments what im using right now for displaying the tabs in the liferay portlet.